# Converting singly linked list to circular linked list by pointing last node to middle node

Tags: c#, singly-linked-list

Given a singly linked list and the middle node's number from the start, I am trying to create a circular singly linked list by pointing the last node to the middle one. I have written the following code:

```
private static void PointToMiddle(ref CustomLinkedList myll, int middleNodeNumber)
{
    CustomLinkedListNode currentNode = myll.Root;
    CustomLinkedListNode middleNode = null;
    for (int iCtr = 1; currentNode != null; iCtr++)
    {
        if (iCtr == middleNodeNumber)
            middleNode = currentNode;
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
    }
    currentNode = middleNode;
}
```

However the last node of the linkedlist is still pointing to null instead of middle node. I understand somewhere I am going wrong, I am unable find it. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you would be able to get this to work would be to change:

```
currentNode = middleNode
```

This line simply replaces the reference to the currentNode object to be the reference to the middleNode object.

You would need to change this to:

```
currentNode.Next = middleNode
```

Unfortunately--unless in your CustomLinkedListNode you've added a setter to the "Next" property, currentNode.Next is readonly, meaning you cannot set it.  Thus what you want is not possible.

Comment: Such an apparent mistake.. Thanks for pointing out. I have a setter already in place and now the code works as expected.